# Prevent duplicate ID in SQL query with JOIN statement

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I am working on a scheduling system. Thus, there are several tables related to each other in order to generate the schedule. First of all, I am not sure if what I did right. I wish someone can help me out. I am using **SQL developer**.

So as I want to generate the schedule, I have to consider 3 tables which are `Availability`, `Lecturer` and Student. These are the table structure.

`Availability`

```
availableid  availableday   availableStart  availableEnd  presentationid(fk) lecturerID(fk) 
-----------|--------------|----------------|-------------|------------------|--------------|
 106100    |  Monday      |    12.00 PM    |   02.00 PM  |  589             |   1001       |
 106200    |  Tuesday     |    12.00 PM    |   02.00 PM  |  590             |   1001       |
 106300    |  Wednesday   |    08.00 AM    |   08.00 AM  |  591             |   1001       |
 106400    |  Thursday    |    12.00 PM    |   02.00 PM  |  592             |   1001       |
 106500    |  Monday      |    12.00 PM    |   02.00 PM  |  589             |   1004       |
 106600    |  Tuesday     |    12.00 PM    |   02.00 PM  |  590             |   1004       |
 106700    |  Wednesday   |    08.00 AM    |   08.00 AM  |  591             |   1004       |
 106800    |  Thursday    |    12.00 PM    |   12.00 PM  |  592             |   1004       |
```

`lecturer`:

```
lecturerID | lecturerFullname
-----------------------------
    1001   |     ABC
    1004   |     DEF
```

`Student` :

```
Studentid | studentName  |  lecturerid (supervisor)
---------------------------------------------------
    1     |     John     |     1001
    2     |    Martha    |     1001
    3     |     Kelly    |     1001
    4     |      Don     |     1001
    5     |     Sue      |     1001
```

Here, `lecturerID` plays as two roles. The one in `student` table is assign as Supervisor. In order to generate the schedule, another lecturer is assign using `lecturerID` as Examiner.

I have done the query. Assuming students under lecturer 1001 will be examine by lecturer 1004.

```
SELECT DISTINCT stud.studentID, stud.studentName, T1.availableID,
T2.availableID,
T1.availableDay,
T2.availableDay,
T1.availableEnd,
T2.availableEnd,
T1.presentationID,
T2.presentationID,
T1.lecturerID SUPERVISOR,
T2.lecturerID EXAMINER
FROM availability T1 
JOIN availability T2 ON T1.PRESENTATIONID = T2.PRESENTATIONID
JOIN student stud ON stud.LECTURERID = T1.LECTURERID
where T2.lecturerID='1004'
AND stud.lecturerID ='1001'
AND T1.LECTURERID <> T2.LECTURERID;
```

My outcome produced all students iterate four times each due to the lecturer has 4 `availabilityID`. Something like this :

```
Studentid | studentName  |  supervisor | examiner    | availableID
---------------------------------------------------
    1     |     John     |     1001    | 1004        |   106100
    1     |     John     |     1001    | 1004        |   106200   
    1     |     John     |     1001    | 1004        |   106300
    1     |     John     |     1001    | 1004        |   106400
    2     |    Martha    |     1001    | 1004        |   106100
    2     |    Martha    |     1001    | 1004        |   106200
    2     |    Martha    |     1001    | 1004...     |   106300
    2     |    Martha    |     1001 
    3     |     Kelly    |     1001 ( and so on to 20 rows ...)
    4     |      Don     |     1001
    5     |     Sue      |     1001
```

However, what i want the result to display is something like this (if possible):

```
Studentid | studentName  |  supervisor | examiner    | availableID
----------------------------------------------------------------
    1     |     John     |     1001    | 1004        |   106100
    2     |    Martha    |     1001    | 1004        |   106200
    3     |     Kelly    |     1001    | 1004        |   106300
    4     |      Don     |     1001    | 1004        |   106400
```

Is this possible to achieve? Each student will have different `availableID` and if it duplicate, the row is not shown. How can I fix my query? I have try GROUP BY, Min(), DISTINCT etc.. they are not working out.

**CURRENT QUERY** (26/4/16) :

```
SELECT DISTINCT stud.studentID, stud.studentName, T1.availableID,
T2.availableID,
T1.availableDay,
T2.availableDay,
T1.availableEnd,
T2.availableEnd,
T1.presentationID,
T2.presentationID,
T1.lecturerID SUPERVISOR,
T2.lecturerID EXAMINER
FROM availability T1 
JOIN availability T2 ON T1.PRESENTATIONID = T2.PRESENTATIONID
JOIN student stud ON stud.lecturerID = t1.lecturerID;
WITH cteStudent AS (
  SELECT StudentID, StudentName,lecturerID,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY StudentID ASC) srn
  FROM Student
),
     cteAvailable AS (
  SELECT lecturerID, AvailableId,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY AvailableId ASC) lrn
  FROM availability
 )
SELECT s.studentID, s.studentName, l.lecturerID,availableID
FROM cteStudent s
JOIN cteAvailable l
  ON s.lecturerID=l.lecturerID
AND s.srn=l.lrn
```

Am I getting it right? I got 80 rows fetched and 0 row fetched... What is the problem? haha

Comment: Use ROW_NUMBER in the JOIN condition.

Comment: SOMETHING LIKE THIS : `ROW_NUMBER =1`?

Comment: No, the ROW_NUMBER of the student equals the ROW_NUMBER of the lecturer.

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY studentid ORDER BY lecturerid)` . Sorry no clue. Can you show me an example

Comment: You need to add this line back to the JOIN:   `AND s.srn=l.lrn`

Comment: Looks right to me.   Can't tell why you would get zero rows for the second query.

Comment: Mannnn haha. Its alright, Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

You want to get a 1-to-1 join of Students to Lecturer's availability slots, and no two students can share the same slot.

You can use ROW_NUMBER to link Student 1 to Availability 1, 2 to 2, 3 to 3, etc.

Here is a pseudo code example.   You will need to apply the technique used here to your actual query.

```
WITH cteStudent AS (
  SELECT StudentID, Name, Class, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY StudentID ASC) srn
  FROM Students
  WHERE SomeCondition='true'
),
     cteLecturer AS (
  SELECT TeacherID, Name, Class, AvailableId
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY AvailableId ASC) lrn
  FROM Teachers
  WHERE SomeCondition='true'
 )
SELECT DesiredColumns
FROM cteStudent s
JOIN cteLecturer l
  ON s.Class=l.Class
  AND s.srn=l.lrn
```

EDIT:

Here is the problem in your latest query (26/4/16)

```
JOIN cteAvailable l
  ON s.lecturerID=l.lecturerID
  AND s.srn=l.lrn
where l.lecturerID='1004'
AND s.lecturerID ='1001'
```

You are joining on lecturerID, so they have to be the same, but then your WHERE clause has 1004 in one, and 1001 in the other, so they will never be the same.   That's why you get 0 rows.

Comment: May I ask few questions?

Comment: What is `WITH cteStudent AS` means?

Comment: The WITH statements create CTEs or `Common Table Expressions`.   You can google that term to find out more.

Comment: ohhh okay. So i have to add this in my JOIN query for student??

Comment: I am getting `ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected` error. Can i show you what I did? @TabAlleman

Comment: Yes. Still getting some errors. Trying to fix it :)

Comment: 0 row fetch... I think I am almost there. But I can't figure the problem... @TabAlleman

Comment: I am not familiar with Oracle, so there may be some differences in syntax that you will have to figure out, but the principle technique will work.

Comment: if i remove `where l.lecturerID='1004'
AND s.lecturerID ='1001'`, Still getting 0 row fetched. However, I just realized, I got TWO query results at the same time, one has 80 rows and another has 0 rows. How can that happen?

Comment: Well right now you've got two queries separated by a semi colon, so the 80 rows is for your first query (the original, it appears), and then 0 for the second query (the new attempt).

Comment: ohhh I see.. Hmm so what could be the problem? `cteAvailable AS (
  SELECT lecturerID, AvailableId,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY AvailableId ASC) lrn
  FROM availability` Probably this part? Cause at first you use Teacher table, i assumed Lecturer (based on my problem). But I've change it to `Availability` because `Lecturer` has no `availableID`

Comment: I got 40 rows now -,- each students repeated 4 times for 10 students... removed what you updated just now

Comment: Update your question with the query that gets 40 rows, please.